# How to update a column in all rows using functions?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I need to update a column in all rows in my table. I have a query which can do it for one row, but how to update all rows iterating each row at a time with a function?

I've tried something like this, but the syntax seems not to be correct.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_file_name()

$BODY$

BEGIN

UPDATE myTable

SET file = REPLACE(file, file, CONCAT(file, 'addingStringToTheEnd'))

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

alter function update_file_name()
```

Basically I expect to iterate every row and update the value of this column "file" editing the string, but I could not find a simple example which does that.

Comment: The syntax looks correct and your update statement has no `WHERE` clause, so it **will** update all rows in that table (the function seems rather pointless though).

Comment: That code won't compile. But with the necessary corrections, it would already update all rows, as your statement has no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It's pointless cause i'ts not the real query, but what I need is to get each row and and edit the value of file (cut a part of it off)

Comment: Which is what your code is doing: changing all rows in that table.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, to update all rows in a table you shouldn't use a WHERE clause.

Here is a simple example that replaces all 'o' occurrences to 'a' in the column text of the table t1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_o()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.t1 SET text = REPLACE(text, 'o', 'a');
END;
$BODY$;
```

To invoke this function use:

```
SELECT update_o();
```